# Eliminate variable x from 2 quadratic equations

Tags: quadratics

The two quadratic equations which I have are

$x^2 - 1970x + 10a =0  $  and

$87x^2 - 3600x + 10b = 0$

I need to eliminate x from these equations such that I get a relation between $a$ and $b$. How shall I do it ?

Comment: multiply the first equation by $$-87$$ and add to the second

Comment: But that will eliminate only $x^2$ term but $x$ will still remain, I want  a equation in  a and b only

Comment: the equation which you receive must be solved for $x$ and this can insert in one of the given equation

Comment: Thanks. It was too simple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the equation that will be arrived is
$$x=\frac{29a}{5593}-\frac{b}{16779}$$ plugging this in your first equation we get (after simplifications)
$${\frac {{b}^{2}}{281534841}}-{\frac {58\,ba}{93844947}}+{\frac {841\,{
a}^{2}}{31281649}}-{\frac {1200\,a}{5593}}+{\frac {1970\,b}{16779}}=0
$$